# fireeye flare-vm: Updating 'python3 3.7.2' to 'python3 3.8.0' failed

Tags: virtualbox, python, python3

I have been trying to install [fireeye flare-vm](https://github.com/fireeye/flare-vm/) when seeing this error at the end of the installation process.

Error Message

```
python3 (exited 1) - python3 not upgraded. An error occurred during installation:
 Updating 'python3 3.7.2' to 'python3 3.8.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'libraries.python2.fireeye' that is compatible with 'python3 3.8.0'.
```

Installation Process

```
PS C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\flare-vm-master> Get-ExecutionPolicy
Unrestricted
PS C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\flare-vm-master>
PS C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\flare-vm-master> .\install.ps1
[+] No custom profile is provided...
[+] Checking if script is running as administrator..
[+] Getting user credentials ...

Windows PowerShell credential request
Enter your credentials.
Password for user IEUser: *********

[+] Installing Boxstarter
Boxstarter Module Installer completed
Boxstarter: Microsoft Update is already disabled, no action will be taken.
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Nothing to change. Config already set.
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Upgrading the following packages:
vcredist-all.flare
By upgrading you accept licenses for the packages.
```

cup all

```
PS C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\flare-vm-master> cup all
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Upgrading the following packages:
all
By upgrading you accept licenses for the packages.
010editor.flare v9.0.2.2 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
7zip.flare v15.05.1.2 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
apimonitor.flare v2.13.0.20160119 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

... output truncated ...

py2exedecompiler.flare v0.1.20180705.3 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
python2 v2.7.17 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

You have python3 v3.7.2 installed. Version 3.8.0 is available based on your source(s).
python3 not upgraded. An error occurred during installation:
 Updating 'python3 3.7.2' to 'python3 3.8.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'libraries.python2.fireeye' that is com
patible with 'python3 3.8.0'.
python3 package files upgrade completed. Performing other installation steps.
The upgrade of python3 was NOT successful.
python3 not upgraded. An error occurred during installation:
 Updating 'python3 3.7.2' to 'python3 3.8.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'libraries.python2.fireeye' that is com
patible with 'python3 3.8.0'.
radare2.flare v3.3.0.2 is the latest version available based on your source(s).
rawcap v0.1.5.0 is the latest version available based on your source(s).

... output truncated ...

Chocolatey upgraded 0/165 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - python3 (exited 1) - python3 not upgraded. An error occurred during installation:
 Updating 'python3 3.7.2' to 'python3 3.8.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'libraries.python2.fireeye' that is com
patible with 'python3 3.8.0'.

PS C:\Users\IEUser\Desktop\flare-vm-master>
```

These are the logs

C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\choco.summary.log

```
... output truncated ...
Chocolatey upgraded 0/165 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2019-12-02 17:28:00,624 1604 [INFO ] - 
2019-12-02 17:28:00,640 1604 [ERROR] - Failures
2019-12-02 17:28:00,640 1604 [ERROR] -  - python3 (exited 1) - python3 not upgraded. An error occurred during installation:
 Updating 'python3 3.7.2' to 'python3 3.8.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'libraries.python2.fireeye' that is compatible with 'python3 3.8.0'.
```

C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log

```
... output truncated ...
2019-12-02 17:28:00,624 1604 [WARN ] - 
Chocolatey upgraded 0/165 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
2019-12-02 17:28:00,624 1604 [INFO ] - 
2019-12-02 17:28:00,640 1604 [ERROR] - Failures
2019-12-02 17:28:00,640 1604 [ERROR] -  - python3 (exited 1) - python3 not upgraded. An error occurred during installation:
 Updating 'python3 3.7.2' to 'python3 3.8.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'libraries.python2.fireeye' that is compatible with 'python3 3.8.0'.
2019-12-02 17:28:00,640 1604 [DEBUG] - Sending message 'PostRunMessage' out if there are subscribers...
2019-12-02 17:28:00,640 1604 [DEBUG] - Exiting with 1
```

Any idea how to fix this? Let me know if more info is required.